# C# how to slide a panel

Tags: c#, panel, slide

This code is just changing location, not sliding.

I am using this at the moment:

```
for (int i = 740; i == 740; i++)
{
   panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - i, panel2.Location.Y);      
}
```

How can I slide the panel slowly?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: This is probably going to be more complex than you'd like. See, like a movie, you need more frames. However, both the `Location` and `TRBL` properties are `int` values. You need `float` values so you can build that effect. This means you're actually going to have to **draw** it.

Comment: Two things to consider: (1) If you are doing this on the main GUI-thread, then it will block until your loop is finished, which is why you don't see it slide. You need to do it in a separate thread, and tell the GUI thread when to update. (2) Even if you would use another thread, it is happening very fast, so you wouldn't notice it. Slow it down a bit, eg. by waiting 1 ms every time you set a new value.

Comment: @neoistheone, float values for pixel-positions? That doesn't sound like a good idea :)
But a custom draw-method might do the trick. Haven't tried it for this kind of "animation" though.

Comment: @LarsKristensen, you know I'd say that, except that the `PointF` class exists for that very reason. :D - There is a big difference between a `Pixel` and a `Point`.

Comment: @neoistheone, True, it exists for drawing custom shapes. But without knowing more context than what the OP posted, it might be a little overkill to make a custom draw method for a panel (and its contents), just to animate the sliding. Also, why don't you use PointF in your answer then? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, as I stated in my comment you really need to use `float` values, so you really need to draw it. However, the current implementation only makes a **single iteration**. The current loop could have been translated into this:

```
panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - 740, panel2.Location.Y);
```

Consider a loop like this to slide it out:

```
for (int i = -(panel2.Width); i < 0; i++)
{
   panel2.Location = new Point(i, panel2.Location.Y);
}
```

That algorithm is assuming that you've set the `Location` to the `-` of it's width (e.g. -740x) so that it's simply not visible on the screen. The reverse would hide it.

This will still be a little choppy, but it won't just *hide it* like your current code.

Comment: Yea not bad . Your thing works like I wanted it to . thanks mate

Comment: Where does the float-values play any part in this? As far as I can see, you are still using Integers and Point-objects :)

Comment: @LarsKristensen, I think I pretty much made that clear when I prefaced the answer. I'm not going to build out a GDI+ example on SO. I offered the OP a possible intermediate solution. Based on the OP's comment, I accomplished that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to slide the panel try to do this

Try this code:

```
Panel panelArray = new Panel[];
Panel panel2 = panelArray[0];



for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - i, panel2.Location.Y);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```